# Booting Android with lilo in a PC

Tags: android, lilo

After installation of android, I modified lilo.conf to boot it. I just wrote

```
image=/mnt/android-4.4-r2/kernel
  root=/dev/sda7
  label=android
  read-only
```

because I saw the only filename that looked like a kernel image was that. But after some chunks of messages output, it said "5 seconds to boot". As I saw an `initrd.img`, I then added it to `lilo.conf`:

```
image=/mnt/android-4.4-r2/kernel
  initrd=/mnt/android-4.4-r2/initrd.img
  root=/dev/sda7
  label=android
  read-only
```

This time the booting process went on longer, but finally it said: Detecting Android and there it seems to have hanged. Any way to use lilo to boot the android OS? Of course, lilo when run did not output any errors.

EDIT: Yes, it is. I got it from android-x86.org.

Comment: Is that the android kernel that you're using? http://www.android-x86.org/